# Injecting parameters from AWS Secrets Manager as configuration

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-aws

I'm trying to retrieve parameters stored in AWS Secrets Manager to inject them into bean using `@Value` annotation.
For example, when parameters are described in `application.yml` I can just type `@Value("${path.to.parameter}")` to inject them.

Found similar workaround called "Distributed Configuration" for AWS Parameter Store [in Micronaut documentation.](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#distributedConfigurationAwsParameterStore)

Is there any way to implement Distributed Configuration with AWS Secrets Manager?

Comment: Just found this sourcecode which looks a bit like that: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-aws/tree/master/aws-secretsmanager/src/main/java/io/micronaut/aws/secretsmanager 

And the artifact: https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:micronaut-aws-secretsmanager

But nothing in a doc regarding this or if it acts as config parameter in bootstrap file.

Comment: @Andreas oh, thanks a lot. As I see, it was added 08-Jun-2021 for micronaut 2.8.0. So great news, time to update old projects :)

Comment: @Shrinath just added separate service for that, nothing special
However, it's now looks possible to implement that from v2.8.0. I'll update post as soon as I do that

Comment: @YevheniiKozii Can you tell me how to use it? Shouldn't there be something in application.yml - but what? And how to access the property then?

Comment: @YevheniiKozii can you provide implementation for this?